# Error changing ascii/binary property

Tags: eclipse, cvs

Using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers (SR1)

When changing the ascii/binary property of a file from "ASCII with keyword expansion (-kkv)" to "Binary (-kb)" [Right click file in general project -> Team -> Change ASCII/Binary Property...] I get the following error:
"Problems encountered while setting file transfer mode
 Reason:
 [Project]: cvs server: admin -k no longer affects future checkins. Use update -k / commit -f instead."

I assume this is a CVS issue (I am not an admin for the CVS being used). Please advise!

Edit: Should mention that it is Release 4.2.1.

Comment: This looks like an issue you should hash out with your CVS administrator, looks like a version mismatch.

Comment: @nitind Release 4.2.1